# C# Screen Scrape Issue

Tags: c#, webclient, screen-scraping

I am trying to write a screen scraper for a certificate verification site. ([here](http://www.asha.org/eweb/ashadynamicpage.aspx?site=ashacms&webcode=ccchome)) I am getting an "Error has occurred" message after posting to the form. I have done a few of these before and I can usually find the issue. This time has been more difficult. Any ideas?

Things I have tried:

- Adding/Removing the HttpUtility.UrlEncode on the name/value pairs. It doesn't seem to matter.
- Using HttpWebRequest. I have successfully used that in the past as well but it basically does the same thing.

Note that I have tried to simplify the code down by putting URL strings into the code. I hope I haven't introduced a syntax bug.

I am using a customized version of the WebClient. The class is at the bottom of the code.

```
client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36");

// Load the initial page to get the cookie and viewstate
response = client.DownloadData("http://www.asha.org/eweb/ashadynamicpage.aspx?site=ashacms&webcode=ccchome");
postResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

start = postResult.IndexOf("__VIEWSTATE");
start = postResult.IndexOf("value=\"", start) + 7;
String viewstate = postResult.Substring(start, postResult.IndexOf("\"", start) - start).Trim();

// post the viewstate and license to the form
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

response = client.UploadValues("http://www.asha.org/eweb/ashadynamicpage.aspx?site=ashacms&webcode=ccchome", "POST", new NameValueCollection()
   {
      { "__APPLICATIONPATH", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/eWeb") },
      { "__EVENTTARGET", "" },
      { "__EVENTARGUMENT", "" },
      { "__LASTFOCUS", "" },
      { "__VIEWSTATE", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(viewstate) },
      { "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("28D90D6C") },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$txtAccountNumber"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("12156995") },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$btnSearchByAccountNumber"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Submit") },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$txtLastName"), "" },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$txtFirstName"), "" },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$ddlCountry"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("c7382b6c-7ada-4276-bc5c-e67f488981aa") },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$ddlStates"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("AL") },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$hiddenStateName"), "" },
      { HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ab88a3d7_f50d_49d8_9557_30ffe94f63e8$hiddenStateCode"), "" }
  });

// Note: postResult will contain the error page
postResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

This is the custom web client. It handles cookies. I think I got the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624624/Using-a-Cookie-Aware-WebClient-to-Persist-Authenti).

```
class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a hidden field that you forgot to include?  Or maybe there is some JavaScript that runs `OnSubmit`?

Comment: I pulled the form elements from a Chrome request I made to the form which worked so I think I have everything. I don't think it's a javascript issue. (Thank you for responding.)